# C++ Use if statements with fstream?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I've asked this question before, but I want to know why I can't get the answer I'm looking for when I run this code:

```
void fourCoats() 
{
    string word;

    ifstream horseList;
    horseList.open("horseList.txt");
    if (!horseList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        while (horseList >> word)
        {

            if (word == "Male8D") {
                horseList >> word;
                if (word == "Female7B") {
                    cout << "You have Male8D and Female7B, Breed them!\n";
                }
            }
            else if (word == "Female8D") {
                horseList >> word;
                if (word == "Male7B") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male8D, Breed them!\n";
                }
            }
            else if (word == "Male8D") {

            }
            else if (word == "Female8D") {

            }
            else if (word == "Male8D") {
                cout << "Some other stuff here, you have so and so";
            }
            else if (word == "Female8D") {
               cout << "some other stuff here";
            }
            else if (word == "Male8D") {
               cout << "some stuff here";
            }
            else if (word == "Female8D") {
                horseList >> word;
                if (word == "Male7E") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male7E, Breed them!\n";
                }
            }

        }
    }

    horseList.close();


}
```

Basically, I want to search a file using fstream and using "if statements" or if there's a better way of doing this, Find a combination of strings from the text file. If that combination is found, I want to output a message as seen in the first couple of if statements, the problem is that I can't get anything to work properly, I'll have the words I'm looking for in the textfile but then nothing will output when found. Is it possibly not finding them in the file correctly? The text is inputted line by line, so what I'm looking for is on different lines and not just on one single line.

Please guide me or assist me in what I'm doing wrong I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I've tried so many things! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you checking `if (word == "Male8D")` four times? If the first check succeeds, the others will  never be reached. Same with `if (word == "Female8D")`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 
wait so I should only use `if (word == "Male8D")` one time, and then if other combinations exist with this same "Male8D" I should just use a else if statement under that first `if (word == "Male8D")`???

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I only did it four times to make it easier to read! Hmm...

Comment: Well, I don't know what you should do as you've never adequately explained what you are trying to achieve. But I do know that what you are doing now is pointless.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik
I'm trying to achieve a "horse calculator" where the user inputs the horses they have "Male8D, Female8D, Male7C, ect" If they have a certain combination such as Male8D and Female8D I want to output something saying they should breed this pair first. I want to make it so the program searches through the text file in order to find the best combinations first and output them to the user so they know which to breed first. It's for a game called Black Desert Online

Comment: What you need to do in order to get good answers: **(1) provide a (short) example input text.**  (2) Provide the expected output you want to generate. (3) Provide a self-contained program with a main function, if you can.

Comment: By the way, C++ is probably not the best language for this - try a script language, or C# if you are on a PC.

Comment: Well, if you need to find the best combination, then it's probably not the good idea to print as you read the file. Say you find some breeding pair, and you print "Breed them!" - but what if there's a better pair further down the file? Perhaps on the very last line? You can't un-print what you've already printed. Sounds like you need to read the whole file while keeping track of the best pair found so far, and then print it at the end.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the value. In this case, that means changing `ifstream horseList; horseList.open(“horseList.txt”);` to `ifstream horseList(“horseList.txt”);`. Also, you don’t need to call `horseList.close();`. The destructor will do that.